# Django - Forms - autofill & hide foreign key field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have **models.py**, and **forms.py** that looks like this:

```
class BHA_overall(models.Model):
    bha_number = models.ForeignKey(BHA_List, 'CASCADE', related_name='bha_overall')
    drill_str_name = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    depth_in = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    depth_out = models.CharField(max_length=111)


class BHA_overall_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = BHA_overall
        fields = '__all__'
```

In my template, if I just use:

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button name='action' value='login' type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

the foreign key field `bha_number` is displayed as a combo box where I can select the specific `bha_number` model instance it belongs to, like this:

[image]

Here, I want to remove `Bha number` field from the user side, and just let my code auto fill that field for the user, and hide it. So from the user side, there will be only 3 fields displayed. How can I do this?

Currently I am implementing this html code:

```
<form id="demo-form" data-parsley-validate="" novalidate="" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for field in form %}
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
        <label class="input-upper-title">{{ field.name }}</label>
        <input type="text" id="" class="form-control input-field-height-vertical" name="" data-parsley-trigger="" required="">
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

And it renders this:

[image]

I want the first field, `bha_number` to disappear from the user side, but the system still needs to get that information to save to a correct model instance. So I'm looking for an way to auto fill this `ForeignKey` field at **forms.py** or **views.py** level.

Here is my **views.py**:

```
class BHA_UpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = BHA_List
    success_url = reverse_lazy('well_list') # this is wrong
    form_class = BHA_overall_Form
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        api = get_well_api(self.request)
        current_bha = BHA_List.objects.filter(id=get_current_bha_id(self.request))[0]
        form = BHA_overall_Form(request.POST, instance=BHA_overall.objects.filter(bha_number__well__api=api, bha_number=current_bha)[0])
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return super().post(request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use exclude to hide the field from form

```
Class BHA_overall_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = BHA_overall
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('bha_number',)
```

To auto fill after checking if form is valid, just clean the data using `form = form.cleaned_data` and store it in any variable. It's nothing but a dictionary.  You can assign value to this like `form['bha_number']  = your value` and save it to database by using form.save().
Or you can use `object = form.save(commit=False)` because this method will  return an object. Then you can do `object.bha_number = your number` 
And finally object. Save in next line. That's all. Choose whatever solution you like.

Comment: how about auto-filling the foreignkey field

Comment: In that case the form validation may not be valid in case a unique constraint including the foreign key is set. How to overcome that?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you keep it as is on forms.py but exclude it from your HTML?  That way the user would not see it as an option but the value would still be sent with the form.